# CustomPropertyDrawer in unity3d for inherited classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do something I think is relatively simple, but maybe I'm way off base.  I don't know.  I have a class that inherits from ScriptableObject, like such:

```
using UnityEngine;
class Automobile : ScriptableObject {
    [SerializedField]
    private int _baseCost = 0;
    public int BaseCost { get { return _baseCost;} set {_baseCost = value;} }
    // More fields and logic
    void OnValidate() {
        BaseCost = _baseCost;
    }
}
```

Then I have a class that inherits from Automobile, like such:

```
public class Car : Automobile {
}
```

This class is actually empty, there may be logic added to this later, right now I'm just keep Cars separate from Trucks, Motorcycles, and who knows what else I'll think up.  I used this [script](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CreateScriptableObjectAsset) from the unity wiki to create a bunch of asset files for different cars.  All are located under the \resources\cars folder so I can load them at runtime

I then have a player class that contains an array of cars (and trucks, but for brevity I'm excluding all that)

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    private Car[] _cars;

    public Car[] Cars { get { return _cars; } set { _cars = value; } }

    void Start () {
        // Load all cars into array
        Cars = Resources.LoadAll<Car>("Cars")
    }
}
```

To cap this all off, and to actually explain the issue I'm having, I want to create a custom property drawer for every object that is derived from the Automobile class.  So I created a script in the editor folder like this:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Automobile), true)]    
public class AutomobileDrawer : PropertyDrawer {
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
        position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);

        var indent = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;

        Rect BaseCLabel = new Rect(position.x, position.y, 200, position.height);
        Rect BaseC = new Rect(position.x + 35, position.y, 15, position.height);

        EditorGUI.LabelField(BaseVLabel, "Base Cost");

        // This is my error line
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(BaseV, property.FindPropertyRelative("_baseCost"),GUIContent.none);  

        EditorGUI.indentLevel = indent;
        EditorGUI.EndProperty();

        //base.OnGUI(position, property, label);
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that FindPropertyRelative always returns null.  I'm almost 100% confident that due to the levels of inheritance I need to build a path (which would present a problem when I move on to trucks as the path will most likely be different), but I have no idea what it should be.  Any suggestions?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the Automobile class utilizes the OnValidate function.  I added it to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to have been that classes that inherit from `ScriptableObject` do not seem to work well with propertydrawers.  By removing the inheritance from my Automobiles class, and simply applying the `[Serializable]` attribute to the class declaration I was able to get the propertydrawer working correctly.

I am hoping that I am wrong about this, as I have some classes that I need to leave inheriting from `ScriptableObject` and hopefully somebody will see this and correct me, but until that time, this is my solution.